# How to fix roughness on the mesh?

Tags: modeling, mesh, texturing, edges, smooth

[image: Rougness]

I tried everything from Merge by distance, subvide, clear sharp edges etc. But kinda not sure how to smooth this without breaking mesh. Does anyone know what is this? here is the mesh file:
[Mesh](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jhfkSTzdYps8tNi13hTqe1zNrYaipn_K/view)

---

Update: Merge by distance is not fixing the error.
When i go in viewport shading view it shows like this:
[image]

It can be shading problems, normals, auto smooth dont have idea.
Anyone who solve this is genius!

Comment: Have you used Shade Smooth on it in Object mode and Auto Smooth Normals? If increasing the Auto Smooth Angle doesn't fix it you may have to remake it starting with more vertices.

Comment: Please show the topology, maybe share your file and show the reference object?

Comment: I think the problem here is, that the screenshot is before merging by distance, and while merging by distance fixes the particular shading issue you present on this screenshot, afterwards there are still shading issues. Those come from ugly triangulation of your object. Those could be fixed in a roundabout way, but the real fix is to just redo the mesh to have a correct topology.

Comment: I tried all... merge by distance, shade smooth, auto smooth normals everything. Is there any chance to fix that shading issues / triangles without doing it all again? Thanks in advance

Comment: @RoriHuston you are not using quad topology, it's all triangles which is bad topology and causes your shading problems. recreate your mesh using quad topology.

Answer (score 1):

> I tried everything from Merge by distance[…]

It doesn't seem so. <kbd>⭾ Tab</kbd> to go to *Edit Mode*, then <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>M</kbd>, <kbd>B</kbd> to *Select All* and *Merge By Distance*.

It fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you asked the same thing here. Maybe my answer to your other question might work: [how to flat mesh and remove rough edges?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/299693/how-to-flat-mesh-and-remove-rough-edges/299715?answertab=modifieddesc#tab-top)

I also downloaded the file and the edges look fine:
[image]

Answer (score -1):

your mesh is broken up in parts, hence the different shading artefacts. Select all the bowl's vertices and select Merge by distance. With a setting of 0.0001 it removes 799 vertices.