# how to flat mesh and remove rough edges?

Tags: modeling, rendering, mesh, texturing, 3d-view

Does anyone know how to flat this mesh?
Whenever i move this mesh, is even more rough. Does anyone know whats is this?

[image: not flat]

Comment: Hello and welcome to BSE. I'm not sure what you mean by "how to flat this mesh". If you mean flatten that you end up with only 2 faces perpendicular to each other, why not just model it again?

Answer (score 0):

The screenshot looks to me likes an Anti-Aliasing issue. The edges seem to be pixelated and rough which I believe is what you meant.

**What is anti-aliasing? -** Anti-aliasing is what computer graphics use to smooth out edges in images. It keeps them from looking like the edges of the mesh in your screenshot.

> **How To Fix It:**
>
> - Go to the Blender Preference Settings. [**Edit > Preferences**] OR [**press  <kbd>F4</kbd>  to open up the "File Context" menu and choose it from that list**]
> - Go to the Viewport tab located on the left side panel
> - In the **"Quality"** section, change the *"Viewport Anti-Alisiang"* to a higher sample count.
>   [image]

Side note: The sample count is set to 8 by default and usually just increasing one step in the list of options will work.

My apologies if it doesn't.